# Why does string concatenation not work when querying LTREE in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation, postgres-9.6, ltree

The following SQL works perfect:

```
SELECT node_path, commenttext
FROM comments WHERE node_path ~ '*.5f985c80_5205_48cd_b198_1734e0a981d4.*';
```

But the following gives me an error:

```
SELECT node_path, commenttext
FROM comments WHERE node_path ~ ('*.'||'5f985c80_5205_48cd_b198_1734e0a981d4'||'.*');
```

The error is:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: ltree ~ text
LINE 1: ...e_path, commenttext FROM comments WHERE node_path ~ ('*.'||'...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s).
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I am not sure what the difference between the two other than concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Adding `::lquery` at the end of concatenation makes it work. So overall here's the solution:

```
SELECT node_path, commenttext FROM comments WHERE node_path ~ ('*.'||'5f985c80_5205_48cd_b198_1734e0a981d4'||'.*')::lquery;
```

I used this to figure it out:

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA+mi_8a2t_d9qbD83SBxwY_OKM1c4iHnceXPOM4fP9X=WGeYfQ@mail.gmail.com